# React js object properties undefined in render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, lodash

I'm trying to retrieve with **lodash** a record from a **Firebase db** as array of objects by using the url param which matches the `slug` property. When I try to show the object properties (example the `url` property) in the render method I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`. If I console log `this.props.match.params.slug` I get the right param though.

here's the object I get from Firebase:

```
   {
       "category" : "illustrations",
       "medium" : "ink",
       "slug" : "black-and-white",
       "thumb" : "https://.....png",
       "title" : "black and white",
       "url" : "https://.....png"
    }
```

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import base from '../base';

class Painting extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      pictures: []
    }
  }

  // firebase syncing
  componentWillMount() {
    this.ref = base.syncState('pictures', {
      context: this,
      state: 'pictures',
      asArray: true
    });
  }

  renderImage() {
    if (!this.state.pictures) {
      return ("Loading...");
    } else {
      return <p>{_.find(this.state.pictures, { slug: this.props.match.params.slug }).url}</p>
    }
  }


  render() {

    console.log(this.props.match.params.slug)

    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderImage()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Painting;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `pictures` is empty, and lodash find undefined. 
Little fix your `renderImage` method:

```
    renderImage() {
    if (!this.state.pictures || this.state.pictures.length === 0) {
      return ("Loading...");
    } else {
      return <p>{_.find(this.state.pictures, { slug: this.props.match.params.slug }).url}</p>
    }
 }
```

So then, after fetching if you will have some items in pictures, this method will be render correctly.